# How to load multiple collections from Firestore that have related fields?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

Let's say I have 2 models.

1. Post
2. Author

The Author looks like below:

```
{
    authorId: 'ghr4334t',
    fullName: 'This is a post!'
    Nickname: 'Avola
}
```

The Post looks like below and will have a reference to the author like below:

```
{
    postId: '12fdc24',
    authorId: 'ghr4334t',
    content: 'This is a post!'
}
```

Currently, when a user clicks on a post, in order to show all the relevant information, I load the data as follow:

```js
getPost(postId).then(post=> {
   getAuthor(listing.uid).then((document) => {
       // update state so I have the post object and author object.
   })
})
```

So the above, I load the post, then I load the author. Once I've loaded them both, I can finally construct a custom object:

```
const finalPost = {
    author: { ...this.state.authorData },
    post: { ...this.state.postData }
}
```

Naturally..If I have a couple more fields that reference other collections, there will be a nest of `get` and `.then()` calls like below:

```
getPost(postId).then(post=> {
   getAuthor(listing.uid).then((document) => {
      getSomethingElse(listing.uid).then((document) => {
         getAnother(listing.uid).then((document) => {
             // finally update state with everything.
         })
      })
   })
})
```

Is there a more a better way to load related information together without having to stack `.then()` calls?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a better way to achieve what you want, with queries directly. Queries in Firestore doesn't provide you with many options on how to query and return data, mainly, when you would need to do any kind of `JOIN` on them, to search via references, which makes the work not very easy. I believe the way you are doing is the best option you have for more now.

An alternative you can try is to have [Subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections), where you will have a subcollection of `Author` inside your collection `Post`. This way, you will only treat with the reference of the `Post`, since the `Author` will be within the document of each specific `Post`. This way, the queries would be more simple, looking like this below. Of course, this would require you to modify your database.

```
var messageRef = db.collection('Post').doc('Post1')
                .collection('Author').doc('Author1');
```

In case you still think this is not enough, I would recommend you to raise a Feature Request at [Google's System](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0), where the Google Developers will be able to check if having a new way of getting data is possible to be implemented.

Let me know if the information clarified your doubts!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! If I understood correctly, I guess my only problem with having a subcollection is that every Post that's posted will have an Author subcollection which is duplicate data. so 2 Post's will have the same Author subcollection. I guess I'll have to work with what Firestore gives me. I'm surprised the team at Firestore haven't implemented something like this sooner. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Zer0 sure, I understand your point. Indeed, Firestore doesn't have very deep querying features, but the duplicate data is something that usually many users have with Firestore, but I understand your point. Please, consider upvoting/accepting my answer, if you think it helped you. :)